# MySQL + Alternative to IN() clause that returns row for each item?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, alternate

OK.. so I had a post here:

[MySQL/PHP/PDO + How to get a row for each (duplicate) entry in IN() clasue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470915/mysql-php-pdo-how-to-get-a-row-for-each-duplicate-entry-in-in-clasue)

Apparently... there is no solution. (or so I'm told)..

So is there an alternative solution to using the IN() clause?  One that DOES in fact return a row for each item passed in...regardless if its a duplicate entry or not?

I have suggestions about using a (self) JOIN.. or possibly even EXISTS...  but I am not clear on how I can go about adjusting my current dynamic query using such suggestions?

```
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($brandlist) - 1) . '?'; //create '?' mark placeholders for query, remove last comma and replace with '?'
//preserve IN() order
$displayList_sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE CONCAT(brandname, ' ', dosage) IN ($qMarks) ORDER BY FIELD(CONCAT(brandname, ' ', dosage),'". trim(implode("','", $brandlist))."')";             
$displayList_stmt = $conn->prepare($displayList_sql);
$displayList_stmt->execute($brandlist);//make note of passing in array as param to execute() call
```

Can this be altered to use a JOIN or EXISTS (anything) so that it returns a row for each item? (which is a dynamically posted array?)

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense; IN does nothing to "distinct" the results. If there are multiple rows that match an element of the IN list, those rows will be included. If there are different rows, with different values (both in the IN list), those different rows will also be returned. _...and what abomination of a database design makes using a variable for a table name a good idea?_

Comment: i think the topicstarter means this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75066f/7 he would then expect two records containing `id 1 brandname a and dosage a` because he is using the same search twice

Comment: Ah, I flew right past the _duplicate_ in "duplicate entry"

Comment: Correct.  There is only 1 ROW in the table.. but a duplicate entry in the IN() clause.  I want a row for each item in the IN() clause.. but my understanding is that is not possible.  So can this be done using a JOIN or EXISTS or something?  The placeholder list and brandList is dynamically generated by user selection from the $_POST[]

Comment: @Raymond Nijland

Your second query returns two rows as expected.. but how I can use that in MY query?  Which passes in a dynamically created array as the items to return data for.. but also to be used as the 'order' (because keeping the order is HIGHLY important here)

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly pretty, but you can "convert" your list to a subquery and join that against the actual table you want to query.

```
SELECT t.stuff
FROM (SELECT 'in item 1' AS item 
      UNION ALL SELECT 'in item 2' 
      UNION ALL ...
) AS inList
INNER JOIN $tablename AS t ON inList.item = CONCAT(t.brandname, ' ', t.dosage)
ORDER BY ...
```

My guess is there is probably some php methods you can use to explode/split the variable you had used to populate the IN list to create the `SELECT ... UNION ALL ...` subquery.

Worst, most primitive case (in pseudo code), assuming a simple comma-separated list:

`theList = "SELECT " + REPLACE(theList, ',', ' AS item UNION ALL SELECT')`

---

If query length becomes an issue, another option is to create a temp table to store the IN list in, and then join against that. (This technique can also sometimes be used to make the query faster; since the temp table can be indexed to help with the join operation.)

Comment: PRETTY isnt a requirement here.. LOL..

hmmm.....  not opposed to it I guess.  Just not sure how to do it yet.

Comment: See edit for an idea on most basic approach to parsing source list. By not pretty, I mean that if your lists are really long you can start running in issues with query length faster.

Comment: the temp table solution would also be eazier to implement and protect against SQL injection with PDO or MySQLi

Comment: @Raymond Nijland

I appreciate your suggestion.. I'm just not that well versed to piece it all together from the example using my query as the base.  I"m not clear where my array and other stuff go to match your hardcoded values)

I would prefer to still have PDO/parameterized protection..etc (not SQLi)

Comment: @whispers 'in item 1' and 'in item 2' are placeholders for your values.

Comment: @Uueerdo

I got stuck in meetings all day.. I will give your manual query creation suggestion a 'go' tomorrow!  Just wanted to say thanks before hand.

Comment: @Uueerdo

For now.. I have hardcoded the query string.. is this syntax correct?

SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT 'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg' AS item 
      UNION ALL SELECT 'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg' 
      UNION ALL SELECT ' SEE NOTES BELOW' 
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Alvesco HFA 80mcg'
)AS inList
INNER JOIN pbaap_drugs AS t ON inList.item = CONCAT(t.brandname, ' ', t.dosage)
ORDER BY FIELD(CONCAT(brandname, ' ', dosage),'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg','Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg',' SEE NOTES BELOW', 'Alvesco HFA 80mcg')

Comment: How does this approach use PDO to sanitize/parameterize the data?

Comment: Also... does each line need the alias 'AS item'?  Or is that only for the first line?

Comment: I am now outputting a query string like so:

SELECT t.* FROM (
 SELECT :item0 AS item 
 UNION ALL SELECT :item1 
 UNION ALL SELECT :item2 
 UNION ALL SELECT :item3
)
AS inList 
INNER JOIN pbaap_drugs AS t 
ON inList.item = CONCAT(t.brandname, ' ', t.dosage) 
ORDER BY FIELD(CONCAT(brandname, ' ', dosage),'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg','Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg',' SEE NOTES BELOW','Alvesco HFA 80mcg')

Is this correct syntax?

Comment: @whispers (1) No real PDO/parameterized query support for dynamically constructed queries. (2) The alias is only needed on the first query in a UNION, but having it on latter ones doesn't hurt and makes them easier to read. (3) Yeah, if you dynamically make your parameters you can use pdo like that. (4) You could actually get rid of your `FIELD()` use if you make the UNIONed queries like `(SELECT 1 as seq, 'item1' as item UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'item2' UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'item1') AS inList`; then you can do `ORDER BY inList.sql`.

Comment: Thanks.. I actually posted a new question (I thought this one was dead already).. on how to keep the ORDER the same as the input array?  Currently.. it seems to be alpha sorting?  instead of following the order passed in through the order by field() section.  what is the .sql in the inList.sql part?

Comment: I believe its a typoe.. but do I really need to do: 

UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'item1'   (item 1 again?)  or shoudl it just be item3.. and carry on?

Comment: @Uueerdo

I attempted to do what you suggested... but its not working..

parsed query looks like this:


    QUERY: SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT 1 as seq, 'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg' as item UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg' UNION ALL SELECT 3, ' SEE NOTES BELOW' UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Alvesco HFA 80mcg' )AS inList INNER JOIN pbaap_drugs AS t ON inList.item = CONCAT(t.brandname, ' ', t.dosage) ORDER BY inList.sql;

Comment: Oh, typo in that last comment of mine. That should have been `ORDER BY inList.seq`